# Office 2016 - reconfigures every launch

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

We have a have a few HP T730s running Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB (1607) with more to come. No matter what I try, Office 2016 gives the message "Please wait while Windows configures Office 2016 Professional Plus" and goes through what looks to be the first-launch steps. Happens with any of the Office apps.

If I launch from the executable from within the Program Files folder, the program starts fine. But, as soon as I try to open a file, it then goes through the same configuration.

I've reimaged the machine multiple times, reinstalled Office, repair installed, used the MS removal tool and then reinstalled. There is a MS KB on it with a fix to remove the click-to-run registry keys, but they don't exist on this image.

Wondering if anyone else has seen this, especially on Thin Clients.

Comment: A thin client has write protection and a really small drive. It is likely the problem relies on the fact that you are using a Thin Client. Do note that a Thin Client really is not the right device to use office on. It should only be used to connect to an online server, nothing more.

Comment: Correct. We're using them in a strange environment and it's above my pay grade to decide to deploy something else. They work with O2013. I just pulled one out of the box new and it seems to work. I'm giong to register Office, join the domain, etc. and see if I can figure out where the issue comes in.

Comment: The problem is that a thin client will reset itself upon reboot. At least that will happen once the write filter comes in. I bet this is your problem

Comment: Write filter is disabled for all my testing. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: running apps using appname.exe /safe works fine.